# TFS checkin list shows only modified files but not newly created files

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs, tfvc

For my project on TFS in Visual studio 2010, I had right clicked the project directory and checked out first. Then I have added and modified the files in the local path in file system. When I come back and do the "Checkin pending changes",in the list it only shows the modified files from local path, but not newly added ones.

How can I get the newly added files as well in the checkin list?

Comment: What version of TFS are you using? How did you add files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add non-project content to source control:

1. Ensure that the items you want to add (for example, the packages folder) are in an appropriate location within a mapped folder on your local file system.
2. In Visual Studio 2010, In the **Team Explorer** window, expand your team project, and then double-click **Source Control**.
3. On the **Source Control Explorer** tab, in the **Folders** pane, select the folder that contains the item or items you want to add.
4. Click the **Add Items to Folder** button.
5. In the **Add to Source Control** dialog box, select the folder or items you want to add, and then click **Next**.
6. On the **Excluded items** tab, select any required items that have been automatically excluded (for example, assemblies), and then click **Include item(s)**.
7. On the **Items to add** tab, verify that all the files you want to include are listed, and then click **Finish**.
8. In the **Source Control Explorer** window, click the **Check In** button.
9. In the **Check In – Source Files** dialog box, type a comment, and then click **Check In**.

Check the link below:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/deployment/configuring-team-foundation-server-for-web-deployment/adding-content-to-source-control

Answer (score 0):

Add them from the source control explorer.

In modern versions of Visual Studio and TFS (versions >= 2012), you can use local workspaces to automatically track changes made from outside of Visual Studio.